# Post pages are redirecting to the 404 page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, post, http-status-code-404

In my root folder, I have installed WordPress. Now I have created a **resources** folder in the root and installed WordPress in that too.

I am able to login into the **resources** admin panel and created pages and posts. Now my issue is that all the posts are redirecting to the 404 pages. I am able to access the resources page. I have some posts in it and when I click on it them it's redirecting to 404

I have updated permalinks but still, have the same issue. Below is the htaccess file in the **resources** folder.

Any idea what is the issue? I am using the AWS server. Do I need to change anything?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /resources/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /resources/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The two installs are using different DB (or table prefix) I presume? Have you configured site settings to include the `/resources` sub path? " when I click on it them it's redirecting to 404" - What is the URL? Presumably this includes the `/resources` prefix?

Comment: @MrWhite, I have two different databases. Pages are working but the issue is only post. This is the URL I am getting example.com/resources/postname .. (Shared dummy url)

Comment: I would try and leave the default .htaccess WP comes with in the resources folder, and only add an exception for anything below this path on the top-level .htaccess. Below the `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` line, add `RewriteRule ^resources/ - [L]`

Comment: Modifying the mod_rewrite directives in either `.htaccess` file should be unnecessary. If it was an issue with `.htaccess` then "Pages" would not be working either - and these appear to be working OK. @CBroe

Comment: @MrWhite hard to tell to what extent what is working here, from the description. _"I am able to access the resources page."_ could just mean that the start page works, and nothing else.

Comment: @CBroe, Yes start page is working but not the other pages. I have contacted AWS and they help me to solve this issue.. There was some issue with this file "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/wordpress-vhost.conf" They have added some code and it's start working